# Django View - Do an HTTP POST, but do not generate a new page

Tags: jquery, django, forms, django-views, http-post

I have a form that has some simple checkboxes. When I do a submit, it does a `post` with the relevant information. The html looks like this

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="c1"  value="c1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="c2"  value="c2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Button">
</form>
```

So when I click on the button, it submits it to the same page on the backend. I actually have some extra JQuery code that appends more params to the `POST`, and that code sits in something that looks like `$('#myForm').submit(function() {})`.

I'm using Django views, and the python code looks like this.

```
class MyView(ListView):
    template_name = "mypage.html"

    ...
    ...

    def post(self, request):
         # retrieve who got checked by looking at POST parameter
         check = request.POST['choice'])

         # make backend call with whatever got checked
         foo(check) 

         # THIS IS NOT WHAT I WANT
         return HttpResponse()
```

At the end of the `post()`, I need to return a new `HttpResponse`, which gives me a blank page. But that's not what I want. I just want the same page to refresh. Even doing nothing would be fine - I can simply ask the user to refresh.

So how do I do that?

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you're asking. If your form is being submitted by Ajax post, then it *won't* refresh.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to respond after HTTP POST is to do a redirect. In this case, you could return a [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/) to the page's url:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
...
def post(self, request):
     ...
     return HttpResponseRedirect(url_to_the_page)
```

You can use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) to avoid hardcoding the url and [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/) to show a flash message after the post.

Comment: would this mean i'd lose the checkboxes that's already checked after the redirect?

Comment: Yes, HTTP is a stateless protocol so that's how it works. However, you can pass data back to the view via GET parameters (e.g. "/my/url?checkbox1=checked").